# Create a face vertex by vertex

Tags: vertices, faces

Whats the best way to create a face for the 4 selected vertices?

[image]

Comment: Select the vertices in vertex mode, press F to make a face. Does that work in this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "best" way in this case? What isn't fine about pressing F to fill a face?

Comment: @JeffLange thank you, your suggestion work. The problem I was having the that I dindt merged the vertices before.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/can-a-punishment-be-implemented-for-using-the-word-vertice-in-a-q-a?s=1|21.4960